# Multiplying numbers in python from number 1, but only to a specific number given by the user

Tags: python, while-loop

I haver to define a procedure, that takes as input a positive whole number, and prints out a multiplication table showing all the whole number multiplications up to and including the input number.
for example, I need this output:

> **print_multiplication_table(2)**
>
> 1 * 1 = 1
>
> 1 * 2 = 2
>
> 2 * 1 = 2
>
> 2 * 2 = 4

So I´ve tried this:

```
def print_multiplication_table(n):
    count=0
    multiplicador=n
    while count<multiplicador:
        count+=1
        print n,"x", count, "=", n*count

    def print_multiplication_table(n):
        num=1
        print str(num) + ' * ' + str(num) + ' = ' + str(num*num)
        while num<n:
            siguiente=num+1
            conteo=num-1
            while conteo<n:
                print str(num) + ' * ' + str(siguiente) + ' = ' + str(num*siguiente)
                print str(num) + ' * ' + str(siguiente) + ' = ' + str(num*siguiente)
```

But that generates a loop that runs forever, and I don´t know how to make it stop.

Then I´ve tried a different, more elegant approach, like this one:

```
def print_multiplication_table(n):
    count=0
    multiplicador=n
    while count<multiplicador:
        count+=1
        print n,"x", count, "=", n*count
```

But it doesn´t take into account the multiplication of the numbers before the one that I´m multiplying (the output is 2x1=2, 2x2=4, but doesn´t multipli 1x1, nor 1x2).

What changes do I need to make? Any hint?
Thanks!

Comment: Your first code never stops because `conteo` is never incremeted in the second loop so `conteo<n` is always True after the first iteration. Also `num` is never incremented, so `num<n` is always True.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a nested `for` loop here.

```
>>> def print_multiplication_table(n):
        for i in xrange(1, n+1):
            for j in xrange(1, n+1):
                print "{}x{}={}".format(i, j, i*j)


>>> print_multiplication_table(2)
1x1=1
1x2=2
2x1=2
2x2=4
```

Your `while` loop doesn't work because you go from 1 to the number and only multiply the number with `count`, hence, generating a sequence like `10x1, 10x2, 10x3...`.

Comment: `xrange` saves you creating a temporary variable.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest would be:

```
from itertools import product

def pmt(n):
    for fst, snd in product(xrange(1, n + 1), repeat=2):
        print '{} * {} = {}'.format(fst, snd, fst * snd)

pmt(2)

1 * 1 = 1
1 * 2 = 2
2 * 1 = 2
2 * 2 = 4
```

Comment: As much as I love `itertools`, I think it'd be best to show OP what's wrong with the current code before suggesting an `itertools` one-liner.

Comment: @Blender Which AFAIK had already been explained... so I guess this should be considered the "non-classroom" way of doing it...

Answer (score 1):

Using a generator expression:

```
r = xrange(1, n+1)
g = (' '.join([str(i), '*', str(j), '=', str(i*j)]) for i in r for j in r)
print ('{}\n'*n*n).format(*g)
```